# profile 2 module with services module

Tags: services, users

i am creating a web service for user registration. I just add some fields in user registration form using profile2 module. How can i integrate this with services module. i just want to make a services with the new fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're familiar with Services.  In your endpoint,
Copy the pattern here:

```
                    array(
                        'name' => 'username',
                        'type' => 'string',
                        'description' => 'A valid username',
                        'source' => array('data' => 'username'),
                        'optional' => FALSE,
                    ),
                    array(
                        'name' => 'password',
                        'type' => 'string',
                        'description' => 'A valid password',
                        'source' => array('data' => 'password'),
                        'optional' => FALSE,
                    ),
```

For your arguments, and add your field machine names.

Inside your callback, you can set $form_state['values'][...] with the passed values, and then use

```
 drupal_form_submit('user_register_form', $form_state);
```

To register the user.